# opinions on primitive double to long addition and back again to double?

Tags: java, performance

Opinions on reliability/viability of doing something like this to workaround IEEE oddities in addition and subtraction etc...? I want to avoid BigDecimal,Formatters,etc... GC overhead

exploring this idea.

```
int fivePlaces = 100000;
Assert.assertEquals(1.13269, add(1.13270, -0.00001, fivePlaces), 0);

private double add(double aPrice,
                   double aModifier,
                   double aPrecision) {
    long price = (long) (aPrice * aPrecision);
    long modifier= (long) (aModifier * aPrecision);
    long adjustedPrice = price + modifier;
    return adjustedPrice / aPrecision;
}
```

for example:

```
    double d = 1.30784;
    double d2 = -0.00005;
    double d3 = d + d2;
    double d4 = add(d, d2, 100000);
    System.out.println(d3);
    System.out.println(d4);
```

the idea is to avoid this result:
1.3077899999999998

and get this one:
1.30778

with primitives.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? If you clarify that, you might gather some factual explanations instead of mere opinions.

Comment: Opinions on code that is already written (and works) should go here --> [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

As for my personal opinion - this code screams "I don't understand how doubles work!!!" at me.

Comment: updated with clarification of intent.

Comment: You want to avoid an efficient, precise implementation that was built for purposes such as yours (`BigDecimal`) because of premature optimization (GC). Your program needs to be _correct_ first, then you profile to find areas that can benefit from optimization _only if needed_.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (context Its not premature, this is an optimization phase) BigDecimal is really not efficient, its 10x slower allocates and churns memory/GC like crazy as opposed to primitive counterpart on the stack.

Comment: @andmer Modern GCs don't suffer much from that churn due to optimizations they make. Perhaps if performance is too slow, just use `int` or `long` as a "count of cents"? If you do not need arbitrary-precision and length, that might work while still guaranteeing precision.

Answer (score 5):

The number `1.30778` cannot be represented exactly as a double.  For this number, the most accurate representation will be `0x3FF4ECAAB8A5CE5B` which is `1.30777999999999994251709267701`.

The core problem with this is **do not use a double to store money**.  Any use of a floating point number will inherently have problems with monetary amounts.

Suck it up and use a BigDecimal.

See also:

- [Solutions for floating point rounding errors](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/202843)
- [Why is BigDecimal the best data type for currency?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228584/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand these things, but was throwing some ideas out working w/o BigDecimal,etc...