# Is this a valid GoF Adapter example?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, adapter

After visit dozens of pages searching a "non-sockets-or-iphone-conceptual-example" of Adapter Pattern, I have found [this one](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/design-patterns/adapter-design-pattern-in-java):

[image]

[image]

> Lloyds bank is an international bank offers services worldwide. For
>   offshore account holders, the tax rate is 0.03%. And, in India it
>   offers two types of accounts, Standard and Platinum. Tax rules are not
>   applied to indian bank accounts. Now the offshore bank is incompatible
>   to Indian account types. We need to design an AccountAdapter to make
>   both the incompatible account types to work together.

So Can this example enough to accomplish the concepts of **object adapter**, **adaptee** and **client**?

Comment: Seems good. I would just name the adapter `OffshoreAccountAdapter`.

Answer (score 5):

This follows the [Object Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Object_adapter_pattern) because the adapter uses the adaptee (rather than inherit from it as a Class Adapter would). One nit pick is it's missing the client from the class diagram.

In this case the adapter is effectively renaming `getOffshoreBalance()` to `getBalance()` and it's hiding a lot of unneeded other methods. I think it's a good example of the adapter pattern.

However, please please please [stop using double for money](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/344327/131624)

Comment: I agree; I just wanted to say - if the client is written against the Account interface (or against the AbstractAccount class), then the adaptee is really being adapted to conform to that interface (or class, respectively), rather then renaming a single method (conceptually, at least, even though this may be achieved through that single method).

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question? The "class" version of Adapter is only possible using multiple inheritance languages like python?

Comment: @celsowm: No, it is also possible in languages where a class can inherit from one class and inherit/implement an unrelated interface at the same time, which includes most OO languages with single inheritance as well. In such a setup `AccountAdapter` would have to directly implement the `Account` interface, rather than inheriting from `AbstractAccount`, to be able to inherit from `OffshoreAccount`.